# Add class to element from other corresponding element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I hope the title wasn't too confusing.

Let me start by saying that I'm no jQuery guru and although I can do some basic things, this one is a little over my head.

**Description**

I have a list of links (4 links), when the user clicks/taps a link the browser jumps to its corresponding section down the page. There's a 'Top' link to  jump back up to the list. Simple.

**Problem**

What I need is a way to add a class to the section that the link the user clicked on/tapped corresponds to.

**HTML**

This is my list of links:

```
<ol class="subjects">
    <li><a href="#folderstructure">Folder Structure</a></li>
    <li><a href="#namingconventions">Naming Conventions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#codingstyle">Coding Style</a></li>
    <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
</ol>
```

And this is the structure for my sections:

```
<ol class="subjects--sections">
    <li id="folderstructure">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
    <li id="namingconventions">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
    <li id="codingstyle">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
    <li id="credits">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
</ol>
```

So what I need is way to add the class `active` to the corresponding section, so if `#folderstructure` was clicked/tapped then the `li` would look like this:

```
<li id="folderstructure" class="active">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
```

If `#namingconventions` was clicked/tapped then the `li` would look like this:

```
<li id="namingconventions" class="active">Heading...<a href="#top">Top &uarr;</a></li>
```

And so on with the other sections, makes sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

Comment: @j08691 You made me think and yes, I was already using `:target` and I needed to target some `:before` pseudo-elements, but it never occurred to me to do `:target:before`, hence, no need for JavaScript... If you post your reply as an answer I can chose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JavaScript here, CSS' [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) (and `:before`) should do what you need.

Comment: Yep, no need for JavaScript. I honestly underestimated the power of `:target`. Here's a working demo using `:target`: **http://jsfiddle.net/9c4es/2/**. Thanks a lot j08691!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('.subjects a').on('click',function(){
   $('.subjects--sections .active').removeClass("active"); // removes active class
   $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("active"); // adds it again
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9c4es/)

Comment: Oh boy, that was easy. Is this part that was tricky to me `$(this).attr("href")`. I made a demo of this whole post here for others to reference: http://jsfiddle.net/9c4es/. A Million Thanks Amit!

Comment: yeah. I'll edit my answer to include that in my answer. BTW, glad to have helped you ;)

Comment: j08691's answer above using `:target` works exactly the same as your solution, and because it doesn't use JS I think that's the best way to go. Truth be told, your answer taught me more than the actual solution to my problem. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it for better efficiency....


$(document).ready( function( ) {
    $('ol.subjects a').on( {
        "click" : function( ) {
                    var sel_href_attr; /* It'll contain clicked anchor tag href attribute valte*/

                    sel_href_attr = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);

                    $('ol.subjects--sections li.active').removeClass('active');
                    /*
                        If you want to remove "class" attribute then you may use below statement 
                        in spite of above jQuery statement
                        $('ol.subjects--sections li.active').removeAttr('class');
                    */    
                    $('ol.subjects--sections li#'+sel_href_attr).addClass('active');
                }
    } );
});
```